# how can show 5 millons of data datatable in codeigniter

Tags: php

I am new in php. I want to show 5 Millions of record from my database in php in codeignter. I am using select star sql query to select table. It's working good but takes long time in loading data into datatable.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

```
<?php
   include('layout/header.php');
   include('layout/sidebar.php');

   ?>
<div data-widget-group="group1">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h2>Data Tables</h2>
               <div class="panel-ctrls"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body no-padding table-responsive">
               <form action="<?= base_url(); ?>signin/sendemailstudent" method="post">
                  <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th style="padding-right:100px;">S.No</th>
                           <th>School</th>
                           <th>Date Of Admission</th>
                           <th>Register Serial</th>
                           <th>Student Name</th>
                           <th>Date Of Birth</th>
                           <th>Father Name </th>
                           <th>Phone </th>
                           <th>Email</th>

                           <th>Pincode</th>
                           <th>Class To Which Admitted</th>
                           <th>Class From Which Withdrawn</th>
                           <th>Date Of Withdrawl</th>
                           <th>Upload By</th>
                           <th>Notify<input type="checkbox" onclick="check();" id="select_all" name="select_all" /></th>
                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        <?php 
                           $i = 1;
                           foreach ($data as  $value) { 

                            ?>
                        <tr>
                           <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $value['school_name']; ?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $value['doa']; ?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $value['register_serial']; ?></td>
                           <td><a href='<?php echo base_url('signin/editstudent').'/'.$value['id']; ?>'><?php echo $value['name']; ?></a></td>
                           <td><?php echo $value['dob']; ?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $value['father_name']; ?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $value['phone']; ?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $value['email_address']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                           $i++;
                            } ?>
                        <div class="clearfix pt-md">
                        </div>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </form>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<?php include('layout/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: -> load the data -> put them in cache -> read the cache

Comment: Either use the server side datatable, having option to show 10, 20, 50, 100 records at a time or use cache instead

Comment: use https://redis.io/

Comment: well, loading *five million records* will take some time - patience is a virtue.

Comment: Paginate or filter.

Comment: You're browser will likely crash because it cannot handle that much data unless it is small. Do as @user2959229 says, paginate or filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone already mentioned:

1. paginate
2. filter
3. 'using select star', dont use the star selector if you wont use all the fields.
4. codeignitter is using Active Record, something that uses DataMapper could be faster, not sure if you can change that though, most probably you can (havent use codeignitter). or using pure php pdo to deal with db.
5. have a look on how to use generators, they're much faster for processing big sets as they dont load everything in memory at once (that's what foreach would do)
6. not sure which version of php you're running, but if you're working on php <5.6 then you should definitely upgrade as new versions use much less memory/cpu for dealing with db.
7. install sql profiler to check if your queries are optimal.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please give me working code snippet.